# There are 5 layers in total, 4 hidden layers and 1 output layers. Is my understanding right?

Tags: keras

I am aware of the neural network conceptually. That is, N layer neural networks usually have N-1 hidden layers and 1 output layers.

Could someone help me understand it practically? For instance, how many layers does this code create?

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I guess that the first call creates two layers, and other calls add one layer each. So, there are 5 layers in total, 4 hidden layers and 1 output layers.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written, you will have your input layer, that feeds into Dense(50), then you are creating 3 fully connected hidden layers Dense(50), Dense(100), Dense(50) and lastly you have your output layer Dense(1)

Comment: Thank you. So, the method `Sequential()` with default parameters is just to add an input layer, does not add any hidden layers, right?

Comment: Hi WXJ96163. You can define your layers in Sequential(). But it is a common practice to first define the model (model = Sequential()) and then add the layers you need. Hope this helps.